# Returning SQL connection authentication scheme

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sqlconnection

DBA/noobie dev here. I'm working out some NTLM/kerberos issues with a user and wanted to create a quick program that creates a SqlConnection to a server(s) and returns its authentication scheme. I can query this information in SQL Server's DMV's but that requires a higher level of permission this user has.
Is there any way to simply return this information? Is it stored in some property?  Or some other library that may include this information

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this:

- Use RunAs to run you program as a user with sufficient permissions
- Use a SQL logon which has sufficient permissions.

The reason you can't get this data is it would be a security breach, so you have to connect with the right level of permissions.

Cheers -